# Does MVC.NET handle roles through cookies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does MVC.NET handle Roles using cookies, or does a controller check with the Role Provider on each request?  Consider this code:

```
[Authorize(Roles="CommentsModerator, SiteAdministrator")]
public ViewResult ApproveComment(int commentId) {
    // Implement me
}
```

Are roles set as a cookie when a user first lots on, or will the `Authorize` attribute check with the Role Provider for each call to this action?

If it uses cookies, it'll be fast.  However, it would be tricky to handle the case where a user is removed from a role unless they log out to delete the cookie.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it would be a significant security risk if the user's cookie value was just blindly trusted.  Unless, it were at least cryptographically signed or otherwise verified, they could just modify it on the client side.

Comment: Matthew F: Yes, of course the cookie would need to be encrypted.  That's what ASP.NET currently does with FormsAuthentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller will check the role provider for each request.

You can override the default behavior with: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.cacherolesincookie.aspx